# How to multiply only a specific element in a vector in R

Tags: r, vector

I have a vector x

```
x <- c(1,3,4,6,4,7)
[1] 1  3  4  6  4  7
```

I need to multiply only the 4th element by 2 of the vector such that new vector y looks like -

```
y 

[1] 1  3  4  12  4  7
```

Any suggestions on how i can get this in R?

Comment: Try: `x[4] <- x[4] * 2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you describe, it's a simple case of multiplying the fourth element by two and then replacing it in the original vector:

```
x[4] <- x[4] * 2
```

This simply multiplies the fourth element by two and then places it back into the original vector at the fourth position, thus overwriting the original value:

```
x <- c(1, 3, 4, 6, 4, 7)

> x
[1] 1 3 4 6 4 7

x[4] <- x[4] * 2

> x
[1]  1  3  4 12  4  7
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option using `replace` + `rep`

```
y <- x * replace(rep(1, length(x)), 4, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Or use an index in `replace`

```
replace(x, 4, x[4] * 2)
```